# How to replace Replace {{content}} placeholder in HTML with text stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page named showdesign.html, it only has 4 lines of code which is:

```html
<script>
var getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("templateType"));
document.write(getData.template_code);
console.log(getData.template_code);
$("#main-wrapper").html("content of placeholder here");
</script>
```

When the page loads, it fetches the html structure from locally stored key `templateType` and object `template_code`. The structure is shown below:

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    {{content}}
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

After the document.write is executed, I want to further replace the `{{content}}` with the key `section231` and object `description`. To do that I have written the code to add sample test in div main wrapper but this line does not work.

Comment: Can you show `i have written the code to add sample test in div main wrapper but this line does not work` please !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this, simply set the `innerHTML` with the value of your storage variable as follow:

```js
// Store
localStorage.setItem("content", "<span class='myclass'>my content</span>");
document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("content");
```

```css
.myclass {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="main-wrapper">
    {{content}}
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Please note**: to run the above script on chrome you have to launch it from command line with this command:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

---

Comment: if i try to run the above from command line, it says 'chrome.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ,  i tried with above code i see this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oowj45sjn8g2jb/Screenshot%202017-05-19%2013.16.24.png?dl=0

Comment: Please, see this [How can I run “”C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669254/how-can-i-run-c-program-files-x86-google-chrome-application-chrome-exe-al)

Comment: still is see `{{content}}` on the page and not `Hello World`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var getData = JSON.parse('{' + localStorage.getItem("templateType") + '}');
```

Not sure but it might work for you